# Making observable NOT to update the input value

Tags: knockout.js

I am using Knockout to post data to a server.

The problem I am having is that the form contains a HIDDEN field with a value. When creating the binding and make it observable, the hidden field is cleared.

```
self.resetCode = ko.observable();
```

If I remove the line, the "resetCode is not defined" error is shown. if I don't use observable and only create the variable as "resetCode = ''", the field is cleared too.

How can I do it?

thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what this value is and is it always the same when the page is opened? 
If yes, you can set initial values of observables like this:

```
self.resetCode = ko.observable('somevalue');
```

In this way your value will not disappear when you create a binding.

Comment: The answer is yes... but I cannot do that.... this is a MVC 5 page and the observable code is in a JS file. The value to be set comes from a database... from a JS file I cannot embed server side code.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem is initializing the value of the `self.resetCode` when the JS is in a separate file to the view that is served up by an asp.net MVC controller.

There are a couple of ways that you could go about it.

The first way is to add a small snippet of JS to the view so that it gets rendered as part of the view.  this object can then be referenced and passed to the page initialization scripts.

The second way is query an API endpoint to retrieve any data that is needed after the page is loaded on the browser but before the page is usable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was not using knockout for this form. I think knockout should implement a way to not clear the bound field.